# Is WebRTC good for non P2P applications?

Tags: networking, websocket, webrtc

I need to create an application where one publisher sends a big amount of data (around 1 MBps) to multiple receivers/viewers using browsers or other desktop clients with relatively short delay (speed is valued over reliability).

I was wondering if a P2P WebRTC solution is good for this, because if I understood correctly it will need to send this amount of data to each viewer individually, overloading the network of the sender (20 viewers would mean 20MBps, which is unfeasible for the average user).

So the solution that occurred to me is to use data channels using a main server as intermediary, but at this point, should I even be using WebRTC or simply use websockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think WebRTC/DataChannels would be a great fit for this!

WebRTC is available for servers in lots of languages these days (Go, Python, Rust, C++...) so building and deploying shouldn't be an issue.

If you are trying to build with a focus on speed DataChannels lets you send lossy/unreliable which will give you a benefit. You will also be notified if you are seeing congestion, and possibly can adjust what you are sending to reduce the loss.

With WebSockets you will get reliable delivery, but you may have issues getting the latency/performance in every network.